# Is there a way to make Jenkins share a common source code directory / check out location for a full and an incremental build?

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Jenkins CI as the build server on a project that I am working on, I am also using Klocwork as a static analysis tool to identify deviations from our coding standards.

At present Jenkins has two builds (being performed in separate directories), a full build on a nightly basis that wipes out the workspace and performs a fresh checkout and full rebuild of everything.
In addition to the overnight build I also have an incremental build happening within 15 mins of a check in. Both builds are using the Klocwork analysis tool.

Klockwork works by displaying a list of potential issues which can then be fixed or chosen to be ignored if they are not applicable to the project, when issues are being ignored Klocwork uses the build file paths to remember where the issues that have been ignored reside. This means that when in Klocwork once I have ignored a warning in the full build and an incremental build is triggered the warning once again returns as the build path is different.

The most sensible solution I can see to this is for Jenkins to perform its full build on a nightly basis but for the incremental build to do an update in the full build location and to then do an incremental build - in the same way that an IDE on a PC functions.

The problem is that I have Jenkins running the full build and the incremental build as two separate jobs which causes them to check out into different locations and I cannot find a way of having the two jobs share a common directory.
Also I cannot find a way of having a single job that performs a nightly full checkout and rebuild, and an incremental build with an update on check in at the same time.

Is anyone familiar with a way of making Jenkins use a common source directory across multiple jobs?

Many thanks,

Pete.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did.

1. Used one job to only check out source code.
2. In other jobs configuration settings', I set an environment variable that pointed to the workspace directory tree that contains the first job's source code (command line access to the Jenkins server is helpful here to figure out where it is, but not necessary). Then in my config scripting in Jenkins in the regular jobs, I 'cd' to that location and use the environment variable as path to all files so these other jobs would use the first job's checked out code.
3. Used locks, so regular jobs would not be running at same time as the check-out code job.
4. Since some results files (because of the tests being run) were generated and created in the source code tree because of the specifics of some of these jobs, in the config post-action script, I copied/moved the desired results back to the workspace of the job that should have them so I could process these results in the right job.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make the two builds share the same build-area,
simply by extracting the files in both build-jobs to a shared location.

I strongly advise NOT to do this, as you can quickly get to a situation where
the nightly-build is cleaning the build-area while the incremental build is still running
(or that the incremental-build is checking-out sources while the nightly is still running).

Suggest you connect *Klockwork* only to one of the build-jobs (the nightly, probably)
so to avoid duplicate warnings.